# Rebind keys to other keys on the fly

Tags: keyboard

So I am making a script for left handed gamers who use their mouse with their left and where if a game window specified is currently active it will rebind the keyboard keys to their gaming keys (WASD to IJKL etc) so that you dont have to rebind all your controls for all the games you play. It will then switch your keyboard back to normal after you click away from the game. I need a fast way to switch keyboard bindings on the fly for this to work properly. I can use ckb-next for this because you can rebind keys on the different modes but that only works if you have a corsair keyboard that is supported by ckb-next. Ive tried using xmodmap but when I rebind things with it the system freezes for a few seconds as it rebinds everything. Is there a way to rebind keys on the fly like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to check out the desktop keyboard layout switcher applet and if it's possible to create a new layout from an existing one, then modify that new layout.

Switching to such a layout should be a matter of only one or two mouse clicks.